# Comparing 2 columns in 2 tables in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to mysql so maybe my question will sound very simple but if some body can help with this:

I need to search 2 columns and output 2 exact columns that have exact string,
for example

```
column1       column2
 sun           sun
```

the problem with this code is that it find this column values too.

```
column1         column 2
 sun             sun
 somesun         sun
```

this is the code

```
SELECT tags.string, tag
FROM tags
INNER JOIN tastings 
ON tastings.tags LIKE CONCAT('%', tags.string, '%')
```

the '%' sandwiching don't help and when I remove one of them I don't get any result. 
for example:

```
ON tastings.tags LIKE CONCAT(tags.string, '%')
```

this code also don't give any results

```
ON tastings.tags = tags.string
```

Comment: Please provide your table structure with sample data.  If you want exact matches, you shouldn't be using `like`.  Your last example is correct, but perhaps the data has spaces or something else that is causing it not to match.

Comment: What columns are you using to join the tables? Do you have a FK for joining them?

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering why this work good when I sandwiching it with '%', so some spaces must to be. then to check it I used trim() function. and it worked :)

what was confusing is that CSV file don't have any spaces

so this is the final code that work:

```
SELECT tags.string, tag
FROM tags
INNER JOIN tastings 
ON tastings.tags = trim(tags.string)
```

Thanks to all who tried to help :)